# Select the first 5 elements from RSS feed with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, rss

I'm trying to select the first 5 items from the following RSS feed XML:

```
<rss xmlns:RTgame="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/xmlns/rtnews/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
   <channel>
     <item>
       <pubDate>2013-03-22 16:45:10</pubDate>
       <title>
          Weekly Ketchup: Will Tom Cruise Be The Man From U.N.C.L.E.?
       </title>
       <link>
         http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1927101/news/1927101/
       </link>
       <description>
          <![CDATA[
            This week's Ketchup includes movie development news for reboots of <em>Escape from New York</em>, <em>Hercules</em>, and <em>Pete's Dragon</em>, the next <em>X-Men</em> and <em>Captain America</em> movies, and new roles for Tom Cruise, Hugh Jackman, and Robert Redford.
          ]]>
       </description>
       <guid>
         http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1927101/news/1927101/
       </guid>
       <atom:link rel="thumbnail" type="image/*" href="http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/14/23/11142332_tmb.jpg"/>
    </item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    etc.
  </channel>
</rss>
```

This is my XSLT code containing the Xpath expression:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" media-type="text/html"/>

<xsl:template match="rss/channel">
    <xsl:for-each select="item[position() < 6]">
        <xsl:variable name="link" select="link" />
        <a href="{$link}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a><br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes" /><br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get a blank page with no results displayed. However, if I change the operator from "<" to ">" or "=", then I get the results displayed on the page.

For some reason it doesn't work with the "<" operator, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just replace**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[position() < 6]">
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[position() &lt; 6]">
```

**Explanation**:

An XSLT transformation is an XML document. By definition in a well-formed XML document any `<` character that isn't use to denote a start or end tag, must be escaped.

Comment: that's perfect! I've spent over an hour trying to figure out what causes this problem. It's good to know about the < character, Dimitre. Thank you for your help.